# chef bootstrap copy private and public git key

Tags: bash, chef-infra

I am new to chef. trying to install a server where I can pull from my private git.

There for i'll need to copy my private and public key to the installed server .

The private key can be located  on the chef workstation machine (I run my server create recipe from there)

I managed to do so with the `$bootstrap_script` I pass to the machine
BUT The private key is hard coded in the code and sitting in the git repo.

I'm sure that's not the best practice.

How Can I read it from the file?
Tried :

```
cat /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa > /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa
```

But the file ends up empty in the machine created.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't really recommend this approach to secrets management given it will be pretty overwhelmingly fragile. You won't be able to change the key via Chef after the initial bootstrap, for example. You can see an overview of some of the available tools in https://coderanger.net/chef-secrets/.

That said, if you insist, you'll want to copy the [existing bootstrap template](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap/templates/chef-full.erb) and create a custom one. In that custom bootstrap template you can add some code like:

```
useradd jenkins # Or something like that
cat > /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa <<EOP
<%= IO.read('/path/to/key/on/workstation') %>
EOP
```

The Erb replacement happens on your workstation before the bootstrap script is sent to the remote host so it will have the content added there.